# Данные для indoor-карт (OpenStreetMap или Яндекс)

Tags: яндекс-карты, карты, openstreetmap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где взять xml-исходники indoor-карт зданий (формата OpenStreetMap или Яндекс.Карт)? Разрабатываем [indoor-навигатор](https://lapkin25.github.io/Nav-any/), и придумали задачу сконвертировать какой-нибудь известный формат в наш формат для навигации внутри зданий. Хотелось бы найти исходники планов каких-нибудь зданий Владивостока в одном из популярных форматов, чтобы попробовать реализовать эту идею.